# How can I show parent and child terms in facet search filter block for a taxonomy field having simple hierarchial select as widget type

Tags: search, taxonomy-terms

I am using facet filter to filter views values . I have a taxonomy term using widget type `[Simple Hierarchial Select][1]`  . I want to be able to filter parent and child terms both in facet filter block

Tax A
-- Tax A child
---- Tax A child of child

I want to use each one of the above as a filter in the facet filter block

How Can I achieve it?

I have ticked 'index hierarchy ' but it just shows the deepest term e.g. "Tax A child of child"

```
http://example.com/admin/config/search/search_api/index/*server name*/workflow
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure how to do this ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm presuming you are using [FacetAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) and [Search API Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr).

You need to add some settings to the facet itself at Search API > Index > Facets > [Taxonomy name]:
`http://example.com/admin/config/search/facetapi/[indexname]/block/field_[taxonomyname]/edit`

You'll need to

1. Expand the hierarchy
2. Treat parent items as individual facet items
3. Don't flatten hierarchy
4. and minimum count zero (ie: show even when empty)

[image: Expand hierarchy]
[image: Treat parent items as individual facet items]
[image: Don't flatten hierarchy and minimum count zero]

Comment: I would give you the bounty because your answer seem very accurate. However, I have not test this out because I find another solution.

Comment: @darol100, could you please share the solution you have found?